# laravel ORM relations : left Join like query with optional condition on the right table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

i have two table, `tutorial:id,title` and `tutorial_tags:id,tutorial_id,title`

the relation in `tutorial` model is defined like this :

```
function TutorialTag(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\TutorialTag');
    }
```

i want to left join `tutorials` with `tutorial_tags` , like (please ignore syntax errors):

```
select tutorials.* , tutorial_tags.* from `tutorials` left Join 
`tuotrial_tags` ON tutorials.id = tutorial_tags.tutorial_id
```

but i want to be able to use Conditions on `tutorial_tags` in case user want to search a particular tags:

```
select tutorials.* , tutorial_tags.* from `tutorials` left Join 
`tuotrial_tags` ON tutorials.id = tutorial_tags.tutorial_id 
where tutorial_tags.title = 'ABC'
```

if i use whereHas like this :

```
    $tutorials = Tutorial::whereHas('TutorialTag',function ($query){
        if(isset($_GET['tag']))
            $query->where('title',$_GET['tag']);
    })->get();
```

i dont get tutorials that are without any tag, basically it works like inner Join.

and if i use `with` :

```
    $tutorials = Tutorial::with(['TutorialTag'=>function($query){
        if(isset($_GET['tag']))
            $query->where('title',$_GET['tag']);
    }])->get();
```

then ill get two separate queries with no effect on eachother, basically the `where condition` on `tutorial_tags` has no effect on `tutorials` and i get all the tutorials even the ones without sreached tag, here is the query log :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [query] => select * from `tutorials`
            [bindings] => Array
                (
                )

            [time] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [query] => select * from `tutorial_tags` where `tutorial_tags`.`tutorial_id` in (?, ?, ?) and `title` = ?
            [bindings] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3
                    [3] => ABC
                )

            [time] => 2
        )

)
```

how can i get left Join like query with optional condition on the right table

Answer (score 1):

This is not an efficient sql query, but you can solve the issue with [laravel collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections) and an extra query.

Grab all the intersections:

```
$tutorials1 = Tutorial::whereHas('TutorialTag',function ($query){
    if(isset($_GET['tag']))
        $query->where('title',$_GET['tag']);
})->get();
```

Grab the rest:

```
$tutorials2 = Tutorial::doesntHave('TutorialTag')->get();
```

Merge both collections:

```
$tutorials = $tutorials1->merge($tutorials2);
```

Comment: your answer is good but if i have 4,5 condition i will have to put query to all of them and merge al data is there any alternative to this answer?

Answer (score 0):

To get the left join query do the following

```
$tutorials = Tutorial::leftJoin('tutorial_tags', 'tutorials.id', '=', 'tutorial_tags.tutorial_id')
                 ->where(function($query){
                      if(isset($_GET['tag']) {
                          $query->where('tutorial_tags.title' , $_GET['tag'];
                      }
                 });
```

This will give you the following outputs:
Case 1: If tag parameter was provided

```
SELECT * FROM tutorials LEFT JOIN tutorial_tags ON tutorials.id = tutorial_tags.tutorial_id WHERE tutorial_tags.title = 'ABC';
```

Case 2: When no tag parameter has been provided

```
SELECT * FROM tutorials LEFT JOIN tutorial_tags ON tutorials.id = tutorial_tags.tutorial_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending a while I'm able to fix this with [Lazy Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading)

```
$tutorials = Tutorial::all();

$tutorials->load(['TutorialTag' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('title', $_GET['tag']);
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `whereHas()` method returns only those models where any relationship matches the condition in the closure. The `with()` method only returns relationships that match the condition in the closure. What you need to do is use them both. You can also use the `when()` method to filter on the boolean condition of the input value being filled.

```php
$tag = $request->input('tag');
$tutorials = Tutorial->when($tag, function ($query) use ($tag) {
        $query
            ->whereHas('tutorialTags', fn ($q) => $q->where('title', $tag)
            ->with(['tutorialTags' => fn ($q) => $q->where('title', $tag]);
    })
    ->get();
```

You also should be following proper Laravel conventions that will make your life easier, especially when sharing code with others.

You should never see `$_GET` used in your code **anywhere**. I've removed it in favour of getting it from the request object, but it should properly be set as a route parameter. Relationship methods that return more than one model (such as a `HasMany`) should have plural names. Relationships names should be in camel case.

Comment: Just realized I spent 10 minutes answering a 5 year old question. :facepalm: